# Parse AppOpened event track push notification consumption via Rest API

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to track an AppOpened event via Parse.com's Rest API, specifically related to the consumption of a push notification via a POST to https://api.parse.com/1/events/AppOpened

Since there's really no documentation on doing this, I was hoping adding a "push_hash" key inside the data sent to Parse would be enough, but I guess I'm just not that lucky.

Does anyone know what the required data for tracking push consumption via an AppOpened event is? I couldn't find anything online and was really hoping someone here could help (especially considering every support page they have points here).

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there poor documentation but from other hands some people already meet this issue. And you can check their code for your situation:

- [Setting up a App Opened event](http://www.develephant.net/setup-and-analytics-using-the-corona-sdk-parse-module/)
- [App-Open Analytic](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Docs/blob/master/en/rest/analytics.mdown)
- [Track App Opens with JavaScript](https://parse.com/questions/track-app-opens-with-javascript)

Try to use anything from this (use app & REST keys) and describe your result more detailed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but we're already tracking the AppOpened event. It's specifically tracking the push notification being consumed (via the AppOpened event) that we're trying to accomplish here. As in, what data needs to be sent with the POST to /events/AppOpened that tells their system it's a push being opened, not just a regular AppOpen. And since the only unique data sent with a notification is a push_hash, I figure that needs to be passed back in some format that I just haven't been able to find/figure out just yet. But thanks for trying~